# Necessity of increasing pressure fluid to pump up water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, centrifugal-force, bernoulli-equation

The volute casing in the centrifugal reduces the velocity as the fluid flows through it, there by in increasing the pressure , 
So my question is
Why is high pressure and low velocity necessary to pump up fluid , why can't it be done with high velocity and low pressure while the Bernoulli's equation still satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never thought about this before, so there may be better reasons than these.

That said, here are a few off the top of my head:

Maintaining velocity vs. maintaining pressure.  If you want to use velocity to raise a fluid, you have to keep pumping more water at that velocity if you want it to maintain its height.

If you were pressurizing a pipe, you can turn off the pump and just keep the system sealed and it can maintain pressure.

Another big one is losses.  If you're pumping the fluid at high velocity you increase the viscous effects which would disapate energy much more than pumping at high pressure and low velocity (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 0):

By Centrifugal, I assume you mean the volute design in a centrifugal pump. This being the case, your assumption that the intention of volute casing is to reduce the liquid velocity is incorrect. The volute is engineered with an increasing flow area. The purpose of the increasing flow area is to maintain the velocity as it collects additional liquid from the impeller, not reduce it. Velocity is just another form of pressure.

In a centrifugal pump, the pressure is expressed in feet of